# An elementary random walk model to incorporate non-Gaussianity

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am preparing a talk for young students to introduce heterogenous dynamics in complex fluids and give them a flavour of non-Gaussianity in displacements which are defined by,
$$
\alpha (t) = \frac{\left< \delta r^4(t) \right>}{3 \left< \delta r^2(t) \right>^2} - 1 
$$

For a Gaussian process $\left< \delta r^4(t) \right> = 3 \left< \delta r^2(t) \right>^2 $, therefore $\alpha(t) = 0 $

I am introducing the concept of diffusion through a simple random walk model on a 1D lattice. In a lattice with a spacing of $a$, the probability of finding the particle at any given site $i$ is at timestep $n$,

[image]

$$
P(i,n) = \dfrac{1}{2} P(i-1,n-1) + \dfrac{1}{2} P(i+1,n-1)
$$

Subtracting $P(i,n-1)$ on both sides of the equation, you get

$$
P(i,n) - P(i,n-1) = \dfrac{1}{2} P(i-1,n-1) - P(i,n-1) + \dfrac{1}{2} P(i+1,n-1)
$$
Multipyling both sides by $\frac{a^2}{\Delta t}$ and taking the limits
$$
a \rightarrow 0 \qquad \Delta t \rightarrow 0 \qquad \frac{a^2}{2\Delta t} \rightarrow D
$$
where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient, we can arrive at the diffusion PDE
$$
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$
The standard solution for this equation (with no absorbing/reflecting boundaries) is given by a Gaussian in $x$,
$$
p(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}
$$
and the mean-squared displacement $\left< \delta x^2\right> = 2Dt$. The non-Gaussianity parameter $\alpha(t)$ for this model is **zero**.

**What kind of modifications I can incorporate to this simple random walk model to have non-zero $\alpha(t)$?**

To some extent, I know that modifying the probabilities of jump to be dependent on the site $i$ will be helpful, but I am not sure how to go about it and further obtain it in the continuum limit.

Comment: Why do you define $\alpha$ the way you do? If $\delta r$ is non Gaussian, $\langle \delta r^4\rangle = 3\langle \delta r^2\rangle^2 $ ie $\alpha = 4/5$.

Comment: If the process is non-Gaussian then $\left< \delta r^4 \right>$ can't be represented in terms of $\left< \delta r^2 \right>$. On the other hand, if the process is Gaussian, then $\alpha$ becomes zero.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant when $\delta r$ is Gaussian. In general don’t you have (when it is Gaussian): $$\langle \delta r ^{2n}\rangle=(2n-1)!! \langle \delta r ^2\rangle^n$$ in particular $\alpha=4/5$?

Comment: I am sorry, the definition of $\alpha$ was for the case of a three dimensional system, in which $\left< \delta r^4 \right> = \frac{3}{5} \left< \delta r^2 \right>^2$. However, in present scenario, I was supposed give it for the one dimensional case. I have modified the definition of $\alpha$ now so that it corresponds to the one dimensional case. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: One thought is that you could reverse engineer it by adding an additional term to the diffusion equation (say one that is non-linear in $p$), and then discretize it and see what probability rule you need. Naively I would guess that you'll end up with a process where the transition probabilities depend not just on the current state, but (say) the past two states.

Comment: @Andrew Wouldn't that only factor non-Markovian nature, as that would only add non-linear terms in time-derivatives? I am particularly looking for something which can incorporate non-Gaussianity.

Comment: @user35952 It will be non-Gaussian in the sense that the solution to the differential equation is not Gaussian, so the distribution describing the process is not Gaussian. Essentially what I'm saying is modify the differential equation in *some* way (add non-linear terms, add higher order derivative terms, etc) to modify the solution. That generates non-Gaussianity. Then discretize to see what "microscopic" process leads to that equation.

Comment: @Andrew Can you please describe how adding higher order derivatives (let's say in $x$) will essentially give me a solution that is not Gaussian?

Comment: @Andrew Also, there is [Pawula's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Moyal_expansion#:~:text=The%20Pawula%20theorem%20states%20that,as%20a%20probability%20density%20function) which states that the differential equation with order greater than 2 the equation has to continue with an infinite number of terms, in order that the solution to the equation be interpretable as a probability density function